# Tikzset with with more than one defaults

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  parallelone/.style={%
    decoration={markings, mark= at position #1 with
    {\arrow[line width=0.5mm, stealth-]{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=2mm]}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
   parallelone/.default=0.5,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[parallelone] (0,0)--(4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I am aware that similar questions have already been asked.)

To deal with more than one argument, I think I need to have `pgfkeys`, but I am still confused (for example, in the above example, things are somewhat nested). Is there a simple tutorial about it? Or can someone provide step by step explanation for the above case? (That is creating as many keys as I may need to change while using it (such as arrow line width, arrow type, length, width, etc.).)

Comment: Maybe you can link similar questions (that you mention in your question), that would make it easier for others to help.

Comment: Which parameters do you want to modify? You can always say `/.style args={...}{...}` or `/.style n args={3}{....}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking about a tutorial, I answer the question in two steps. (IMHO the pgfmanual is an excellent tutorial, in particular when you use it to understand examples that you can find on this site.) You *can* make an style depend on several parameters. But then you always need to specify all of them if you want to change just one. Therefore, I would like to argue that it is easier to store the parameters in pgfkeys with default value. This leads to

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  parallelone arrow length/.initial=2.5mm,
  parallelone arrow width/.initial=2mm,
  parallelone arrow type/.initial=Latex,
  parallelone/.style={%
    decoration={markings, mark= at position #1 with
    {\arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow type}[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow length}, 
    width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow width}]}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
   parallelone/.default=0.5
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[parallelone] (0,0)--(4,4);    
    % change the length and poisition
    \draw[parallelone=0.7,parallelone arrow length=5mm] (1,0)--(5,4);
    % change the type. the length is back to its initial or default values
    \draw[parallelone,parallelone arrow type=Stealth] (2,0)--(6,4);
    % change the width. the other paraneters are at their initial or deault values
    \draw[parallelone,parallelone arrow width=5mm] (3,0)--(7,4);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, at a given point you may decide that you do not want to always type `parallelone arrow` before `type`, `length` and so on. This is what key families are for. Then you may only say `\draw[parallelone={type=Stealth}]` if you want to change the type and leave everything else at their default values.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  parallelone/.style={%
    /utils/exec=\tikzset{parallelone arrow/.cd,#1},
    decoration={markings, mark= at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/pos} with
    {\arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/type}[%
    length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/length},%
    width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/width}]}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
  parallelone/.default={pos=0.5},
  parallelone arrow/.is family,
  parallelone arrow/.cd,
  pos/.initial=0.5,
  length/.initial=2.5mm,
  width/.initial=2mm,
  type/.initial=Latex,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[parallelone] (0,0)--(4,4);    
    % change the length and poisition
    \draw[parallelone={pos=0.7,length=5mm}] (1,0)--(5,4);
    % change the type. the length is back to its initial or default values
    \draw[parallelone={type=Stealth}] (2,0)--(6,4);
    % change the width. the other parameters are at their initial or deault values
    \draw[parallelone={width=5mm}] (3,0)--(7,4);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want two arrows with the same functionality, you could try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  parallelone/.style={%
    /utils/exec=\tikzset{parallelone arrow/.cd,#1},
    decoration={markings, mark= at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/pos} with
    {\arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/type}[%
    length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/length},%
    width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/width}]}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
  paralleltwo/.style={%
    /utils/exec=\tikzset{parallelone arrow/.cd,#1},
    decoration={markings, mark= at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/pos} with
    {\arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/type}[%
    length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/length},%
    width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/width}]%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/type}[%
    length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/length},%
    width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parallelone arrow/width}]}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  },
  parallelone/.default={pos=0.5},
  parallelone arrow/.is family,
  parallelone arrow/.cd,
  pos/.initial=0.5,
  length/.initial=2.5mm,
  width/.initial=2mm,
  type/.initial=Latex,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[paralleltwo] (0,0)--(4,4);    
    % change the length and poisition
    \draw[parallelone={pos=0.7,length=5mm}] (1,0)--(5,4);
    % change the type. the length is back to its initial or default values
    \draw[parallelone={type=Stealth}] (2,0)--(6,4);
    % change the width. the other parameters are at their initial or deault values
    \draw[parallelone={width=5mm}] (3,0)--(7,4);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to have something like `parallelone=0.3 and 0.7`, because as I can see `parallelone arrow length` is totally not related to `parallelone`.

Comment: @JouleV One can do that, yes, but I wouldn't want to do that because you will always have to add the information on all the arrow details if you just want to move the position.

Comment: @marmot Just to clarify: (1) Is `\arrow[line width=0.5mm]` included in the keys? (2) How do I change `>` to `>>` ?

Comment: @blackened `[line width=0.5mm] ` is not included, but it has no effect, I just forgot to drop that key. The arrow is completely determined by the other parameters (in this example). And a double arrow can be obtained as usual, i.e. by repeating arrow, see e.g. at the bottom of p. 210 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: @marmot When I want to customize the arrow length and width proportionally, is there way to do so—something like `scale`—, or do I need to enter both the width and the length manually?

Comment: @blackened The arrow sizes will increase proportionally when you increase the line width. If you do not want to increase the line width, AFAIK you need to adjust both the `length` and the `width` separately.

Comment: @marmot What am I supposed to do to avoid the `I don't know the key ... length` type of errors when I try something like `\draw[parallelone={width=4mm, type=Computer Modern Rightarrow[line cap=round]}]`

Comment: @blackened Try `\draw[parallelone={width=4mm, type={Computer Modern Rightarrow[line cap=round]}}]`.